# How to send a variable by url by middleware

Tags: laravel

Hello I need to return to this page but sending that variable, but it returns this error.

**Argument 2 passed to Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse::__construct() must be of the type int, array given, called in C:\wamp64\www\portalmecanico_copia\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Redirector.php on line 203**

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $id = $request->route()->parameter('url');
    $ip = request()->ip();

    $accesos = DB::table('users')->where([
                    ['id', '=', $id],
                    ['ip_acceso', '=', $ip]])
                    ->get();

    if(!$accesos->isEmpty()){
        foreach ($accesos as $acceso) {
            if($acceso->ip_acceso == $ip){
                return;
            }else{
                return redirect('error_ip');
            }
        }
    }else{
        return redirect('acceso', ['url' => $id]);
        
        //It is in this part
    }
}
```

I want to return to this page.

**web.php**

```
Route::get('acceso/{url}', 'AccesoController@index')->name('acceso')->middleware('checkip');
```

And as I concatenate it to a form

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('login', ['url' => 'It is in this part' ]) }}" aria-label="{{ __('Login') }}">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second parameter to the `redirect()` method should be a HTTP status code which is essentially an int. To pass route parameters while redirecting to a named route can be done like so

```php
else{
    return redirect()->route('accesso', ['url' =>  $id]);
        
    //It is in this part
}
```

Laravel docs: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/responses#redirecting-named-routes